# jquery cycle using multiple slideshow with nav for each slideshow

Tags: jquery, function, slideshow, nav, jquery-cycle

I'm using jquery Cycle version 1 for my website to display multiple slideshow on the same page.
I don't know how many slideshow I'm gonna use so I can't give to each slideshow a unique ID.
here is the code i'm using which works perfectly fine :

```
 $('.slideshow').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.cycle({
            timeout:0,
            fx:       'none',
            next:     $this,

        });
    });
```

all my slideshows are independent, and when clicking on slideshow the next function works on the selected slideshow, that's perfect.

now I'm trying to add a pager to the slideshow, and that's my problem.
pager are synchronized, and when using for example 3 slideshow, 1st slideshow pager displays pager 1,2 and 3... slideshow 2 displays pager 2 and 3, and slideshow 3 displays pager 3.

here is the code I tried :

```
 $('.slideshow').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.after('<div class="nav">').cycle({
            timeout:0,
            fx:       'none',

            // use slideshow as the transition trigger
            next:     $this,
            pager:  '.nav',

        });
    });
```

I need to link the pager to the slideshow, maybe using $this, but I can't find out how to do it...

here is JSfiddle to see it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/HuNfz/198/

thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but there is no other solution then giving unique ID.